# How to replace entries in a string array with cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a string array property like so:

`["name1", "name2", "name3", "name2", "name4"]`

I would like to replace in this array e.g. "name2" with "name5":

`["name1", "name5", "name3", "name5", "name4"]`

So far i came up with a query like this:

```
MATCH (parent)-[rel]->(child)
WHERE 'name2' IN rel.names 
SET rel.names = [x IN (rel.names+['name5']) WHERE x<>"name2"]
```

Which results in nearly what i want:
`["name1", "name3", "name4", "name5"]`

The problem of this query is obvious - it just add's only **one** times "name5" statically without checking how often "name2" is in the array. For example if I have "name2" **n-times** the query only add's **one** "name5" instead of n-times.

Without the "where clause" the query add's a "name5" to arrays that doesn't even have a "name2" included. The right approach should be that the query should instead find 0 times "name2" and add 0 times "name5". So the where part shouldn't be required. How would you solve the problem and is my solution approach the right way to go?

Comment: And your question is? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thank you for the hint I reformulated the question and I hope I'm more precisely now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
MATCH (parent)-[rel]->(child)
WHERE 'name2' IN rel.names 
SET rel.names = [x IN rel.names | CASE WHEN "name2" = x THEN "name5" ELSE x END]
```

Comment: I tried it out yesterday and it worked perfectly thank you :- )